# Find and manipulate a React.js component from the JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, console, reactjs

When I work with JS I tend to whip out a console for the browser and manipulate values on the fly.

I have a page where I use React to render some components and I had the idea that it would be great to be able to manipulate it's state from the console to debug a design quirk which is only visible if the component is in a corner-case state.

I ran into problem that I was unable to get hold of a reference to my component.

I figured there might be a list of active components currently being rendered somewhere, but I was not able to find one on the React global object or anywhere else.

**Is there an exposed reference to the components being rendered?**

I'm rendering the component like:

```
<script>React.render(React.createElement(Comp, domElem))</script>
```

I could store a reference to the result of `React.createElement()` but it [seems to be an antipattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/reactjs/pyUZBRWcHB4/4gnxlVQZF0MJ). Also I'm using the ReactJS.NET library to handle server-side rendering for me so the whole `React.render` line is generated and is hard to modify.

My other idea was to create a mixin that makes the component explicitly expose itself on mount, like:

```
var ActiveComponents = [];
var debugMixin = {
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var id = this.getDOMNode().id;
        ActiveComponents[id] = {
            id: id,
            getState: () => { return this.state; },
            setState: (state) => { this.setState(state); },
            comp: this
        };
    }
};
```

**Are there drawbacks for an approach like this? Is this the same antipattern mentioned above?**

Although being much cleaner than entangling these test hooks in the component code directly, adding a mixin is still a modification, and I would like to avoid that if possible.

The questions I hope to get answers for are bolded.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for this is to assign your object to the window object:

```
window.myStateObject = myStateObject
```

and then you can inspect it in the console:

```
window.myStateObject
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a ReactJS extension for Chrome that may meet your needs https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

If that isn't good enough, React keeps track of all the mounted components in a private variable `instancesByReactID`. If you just want to access these for debugging, you could modify the React code and expose that variable as a global.